# validator must be of the type array in laravel5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3

ERROR:
[image]

I am trying to login as admin and i am defined the guards but there is an error in the validator that validator() must be of the type array in 158 line.

BranchController:

```
    public function authenticateBranchAdmin(Request $request){
        $validator = Validator($request, [
Line 158->          'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if($validator->passes()){
            if(Auth::guard('branch')->attempt([
                'email' =>  $request->email,
                'password'  =>  $request->password,
            ])){
                return redirect('/branch'.'/'.Auth::guard('branch')->id);
            }else{
                if($this->AdminIsVerified($request->email)){
                    $request->session()->flash('message', 'Invalid email or password!');
                }else{
                    $request->session()->flash('message', 'Please Register this Account!');
                }
                return redirect('/Admin/login');
            }
        }else{
            return redirect('/Admin/login')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `$request` to `array`, as `array` is expected by `Validator`, so instead of `$request` use `$request->all()`.